# First problem faced on doing first python programme

Tags: python

Sir I am beginner for learning python please help me to find this brunch of statements

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'printf' is not defined
```

I couldn't understand this expressions please help me to understand.

To fix the error .

Comment: Please provide more code so we can actually see where the problem is. That said, the second error may be fixable by using "print" instead of "printf". Please read over this page on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to post your code. The error mentions `printf` but you didn't show any code using that name.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your code, so it is hard to say exactly where the error is. But as the traceback says "NameError: name 'printf' is not defined".

I assume you have

```
printf("something")
```

And the correct way is

```
print("something")
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)